# Por qué el arreglo actualiza cada elemento cuando actualizo un elemento?

Tags: java, arraylist, set

```
ArrayList<Memory> memories = new ArrayList<>();
    memories.add(new Memory());
    memories.add(new Memory());
    memories.add(new Memory());

    ArrayList<Process> processes = new ArrayList<>();
    Process p1 = new Process("p1",0,800,2, Color.BLUE); processes.add(p1);
    Process p2 = new Process("p2",0,200,2, Color.YELLOW); processes.add(p2);
    Process p3 = new Process("p3",0,200,3, Color.RED); processes.add(p3);

    for (int i = 0; i < memories.size(); i++) {

        memories.set(i, i != 0 ? memories.get(i-1) : new Memory());
        Memory m = memories.get(i).bestSlot(processes.get(i));
        memories.set(i,m);
    }

    for(int j = 0; j < memories.size(); j++){
        System.out.println(memories.get(j));
    }
```

Cada vez que actualizo un elemento, sea eliminar algo o añadir, se refleja en los elementos anteriores también.

La salida es algo como esto:

```
[ ( 0: 800 | Process: p1)  ( 1: 200 | Process: p2)  ( 2: 200 | Process: p3)  ( 3: 800 ) ]
[ ( 0: 800 | Process: p1)  ( 1: 200 | Process: p2)  ( 2: 200 | Process: p3)  ( 3: 800 ) ]
[ ( 0: 800 | Process: p1)  ( 1: 200 | Process: p2)  ( 2: 200 | Process: p3)  ( 3: 800 ) ]
```

Cuando debería dar algo como esto:

```
[ ( 0: 800 | Process: p1)  ( 1: 1200 ) ] 
[ ( 0: 800 | Process: p1)  ( 1: 200 | Process: p2)  ( 2: 1000 ) ] 
[ ( 0: 800 | Process: p1)  ( 1: 200 | Process: p2)  ( 2: 200 | Process: p3)  ( 3: 800 ) ]
```

Los cambios empiezan a ocurrir cuando uso el método bestSlot, que no debería poder acceder a los elementos de la lista, entonces dudo que este sea el problema

Aquí está el código entero: [repositorio](https://github.com/ear64-ua/SO)

El método de bestSlot es el siguiente:

```
public Memory bestSlot(@NotNull Process process) {

    int i = 0;
    int position=0;
    boolean allowed = false;
    Slot oldSlot = new Slot(size,i);
    Slot bestSlot = new Slot(size+1,i);

    if(!isSpace(process.getMemory()) || containsProcess(process)) {
        return null;
    }

    for (Map.Entry<Slot,Process> pairEntry: memory.entrySet() ) {

        if (pairEntry.getValue()==null){
            
            if (( pairEntry.getKey()).getSpace() == process.getMemory()){
                process.setSlot(pairEntry.getKey());
                process.setPosition(pairEntry.getKey().getX());
                memory.put((pairEntry.getKey()),process);

                return this;
            }
            
            else if ((pairEntry.getKey()).getSpace() > process.getMemory()){
                // si el tamaño del hueco auxiliar sigue siendo grande, entonces reemplazar por este
                if(bestSlot.getSpace() > (pairEntry.getKey()).getSpace()){
                    allowed = true;
                    oldSlot=pairEntry.getKey();
                    position = (pairEntry.getKey()).getX();

                    bestSlot.setSpace(process.getMemory());
                    bestSlot.setX(i);
                    //memory.remove(((Slot) pairEntry.getKey()));

                }
            }
        }

        i++;
    }

    if (allowed){
        pushSlots(position+1);
        // eliminamos el hueco que va a ser reemplazado por el resto 
        memory.remove(oldSlot,null);
        oldSlot.setSpace(oldSlot.getSpace()-process.getMemory());
        oldSlot.setX(position+1);
        memory.put(oldSlot,null);
        process.setSlot(bestSlot);
        memory.put(bestSlot,process);
    }

    return this;
}
```

Dicho método analiza los mejores huecos que existen para cada proceso que se pasa por parámetro, haciendo los ajustes necesarios tales como dejar el resto del espacio que está ocupando y si es necesario hacer un push con los elementos del mapa que están por delante

Comment: Dos comentarios: A) en el primer for traes el `memories(i-1)`, ahí replicas lo que estaba en el espacio anterior excepto para el primero. B) no sabemos qué hace `bestSlot` para saber si `memories.set(i, m)` cambia en algo el contenido.

Comment: Claro, quiero editar los siguientes elementos basándome el en anterior. De ahí bestSlot lo que hace es como ves asignar un espacio para un proceso y deja el resto vacío. Lo que estoy intentando hacer se refleja en el tercer bloque de código

Comment: En el primero, lo que hace es básicamente asignar un espacio vacío de 2000

Comment: A nadie en este foro le consta que bestSlot haga algo porque no sabemos qué hace. No hay debug y no es claro por qué ese método cambiaría algo. Comparte el código relacionado :)

Comment: He pasado el link del repositorio de github, aún así lo editaré

Comment: Las preguntas aquí deben ser autocontenidas para que en el futuro sirvan a otros con el mismo problema. No deben depender de que tu repo exista, tu cuenta exista, etc. 
Recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender el sitio y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. 
También estaría bien que revisaras [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que recibas respuesta cuanto antes.

Comment: @Alfabravo vale tienes toda la razón, soy un poco novato en esto, ya fue editada

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cuando obtienes la `memories(i-1)`, no estás obteniendo la instancia de la clase sino la referencia al lugar en memoria. Por eso, cuando la modificas y la asignas en `i`, realmente cambiaste lo que tenías en la posición anterior y asignaste la referencia en memoria (la dirección) a ambas posiciones del arreglo. En la tercera iteración, mismo asunto. Realmente tienes tres posiciones del arreglo apuntando a la misma instancia de `Memory`, sin importar lo que hagas al comienzo.

Mi sugerencia es que crees siempre una nueva instancia de `Memory` y, en vez de hacer

```
memories.set(i, i != 0 ? memories.get(i-1) : new Memory());
```

crees una copia completa (un deep copy) y así no te lías con referencias a instancias ya existentes. No he ido ni la primera vez a tu repo, entonces puede que requieras crear un constructor nuevo que reciba un Memory y así poder asignarle a la nueva instancia lo que contenía la anterior. Algo así:

```
memories.set(i, i != 0 ? new Memory(memories.get(i-1)) : new Memory());
```

Comment: Tuve que hacer una copia profunda entera del TreeMap<Slot,Process> que contiene Memory, porque al hacer lo que me dices ya arreglaba el problema pero me daba otro. Muchas gracias <3